# Best way too check the false & true condition in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what is the best way to check the false & true condition in this case, i have a state set to false initially

```
status: false,
```

The status changes to true if a certain props is present (data-widget) do i need to add the ="true" to the attribut?

```
<div id="app" data-widget></div>
// Is it the same thing or i don't need to add the ="true" to the attribut
<div id="app" data-widget="true"></div>
```

Here is how i check a condition, i am confused which one i should use :

```
//Option 1
newData.status = this.props.widget ? true : false
//Option 2
newData.status = (typeof this.props.widget !== "undefined") ? true : false
```

Is there a better/correct way to handle the false & true condition?

Comment: Try `Boolean(this.props.widget)` or this.props.widget === true

Comment: Consider upvote on the accepted answer ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better/correct way to handle the false & true condition?

There's no "*the best"* way, it all depends on conditions. Even if they are looking similar they strongly differ. The first option will evaluate to `true` if `props.widget` is *truthy* - (it's either an *array*, *object*, true, number (different that `0`) or a non-empty string.

However the second one will evaluate to `true` if `props.widget` is **not equal** to *undefined*. It will evaluate to `false` ONLY if `props.widget` is `undefined`.

Anyways, if it's acceptable for your conditions, I would go with simple checking the *truthyness* of `props.widget`:

```
newData.status = Boolean(this.props.widget); // will evaluate to true or false
                                             // with no need to use ternary
```

Answer (score 0):

They are both same, but  'option2' is just checking if the value exist and is better for handling errors. So I think it will be better to use the second option. And some attributes have default value, I think "data-widget" have default true